# Jquery Templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am using Jquery templates to display incoming JSON data
I would like to load the template in a cacheable external file. How do I do this?

**UPDATE**
http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/
very close to the solution I ended up with, I just used a iframe instead;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These 2 pages seem to give the answer quite nicely:

- [jQuery Templates : Beyond The Basics : The Why And How](http://web.archive.org/web/20130409025845/http://schalk-neethling.com/2010/10/jquery-templates-beyond-the-basics-the-why-and-how)
- [jQuery Templates : Create, Compile, Cache and Render](http://web.archive.org/web/20130326083154/http://schalk-neethling.com/2010/10/jquery-templates-create-compile-cache-and-render/)

Comment: @SvenHecht Thanks for noticing, I have updated the links to their new domain

Comment: Links are dead again (still?)

Comment: Dead again, I linked to the web archive now (I could not find a location for the blog again...) Thanks for notifying!

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be several techniques to implement this each with its advantages/disadvantages.

1)Use a inline script block. This would bring the template blocks with each page load. If parent page is non-cacheable, it could get heavy with multiple templates

2)Access templates via a global variable object in an external javascript file. This is cacheable but template strings become hard to decipher

3)Template strings come as a part of JSON response. This begs the question, why not server side templating?

4)Use a static iframe and compile the templates on iframe load - this is cacheable, templates are readable/editable, same-origin policy could be a problem if static elements are placed on another domain

I finally opted for the iframe approach, but am too inexperienced to be aware of all pitfalls.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use ajax calls against server side resource, aspx in this example

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: "myprog.aspx", 
   data: { whichTemplate: "template I'm Looking for" }, 
   success: function(result) { 
                 // result is the text string containing either a single template or a delimated list of templates 
                 $.template('templatename', result); 
            } , 
   dataType: "text"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code can help:

```
<script id="entry_show_template" defer type="text/html">
  <div class="entry">
    Age: <span class="age"></span> <a class="name" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</script>
```

Maybe you could use this code also with src attribute, scripts are accessible so:

```
$('#entry_show_template')
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer for [jQuery templates - where should I put them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719828/jquery-templates-where-should-i-put-them/7287029#7287029)

In addition to [the article from Dave Ward](http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/) that you mentioned in your question, it references some additional tricks from [An Introduction to jQuery Templates, by Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx). In particular, it covers how to fetch the template once and cache a compiled version of it.