# Where to keep html templates?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, jquery-templates

I have a single page app. Currently my templates stored in index.html e.g.

```
 <script id="button" type="text/html">
    <a class="button" href="#" id="${id}">
       ${value}
    </a>
 </script>
```

Is it a best practice to store them in such way?
I've found [jQuery templates - where should I put them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719828/jquery-templates-where-should-i-put-them) but there is no acceptable answer.

Comment: By "no acceptable answer" do you mean "no generally accepted answer"?  Or are you asking an alternative to the answers there which you consider unacceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing it right. There is no need to add unnecessary complexity to a single-page app, according to the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

> Most systems work best if they are kept simple rather than made complex; therefore simplicity should be a key goal in design and unnecessary complexity should be avoided.

Comment: I really like this answer and referenced it in my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719828/jquery-templates-where-should-i-put-them/7287029#7287029